# Do i need to build separate spark jar for each of my use case?

Tags: apache-spark

My problem is that i have multiple use cases to solve. Ex - Say I have all states of a country data in a json file.

```
[{
    "name": "Karnatka",
    "capital": "Bengaluru",
    "CM": "Swamy",
    "population": 10000000
},
{
    "name": "Tamilnadu",
    "capital": "Chenaai",
    "CM": "XYZ",
    "population": 200000
},
{
    "name": "Kerala",
    "capital": "Trichi",
    "CM": "ABCD",
    "population": 3000000
}]
```

Now say that i have below use cases -

- Find out  top  populated state and write to hdfs
- Find out capital of each state write to some custom UI
- find out chief minister of each state and write to hdfs

So do i need to build separate jar for each use case or i can do this in single spark application. 
And how can i schedule this application in cluster to run daily?

Comment: 1 and 3 can be done in the same JAR. 2 can be accommodate depending on what "custom UI" is. JAR can be schedule via a CRON Job, Autosys Scheduling or any other Scheduler of your preference. Voting to close the question as too broad in it's current state.

Comment: What i wanted to state is say at one time only one use case should be run. And at the same time some dynamic query can come.

Comment: https://livy.incubator.apache.org/

Comment: Shall i write multiple small spark application for each of my use case and run them separately as the frequency to run each use case can be different?? Or  i shall club them in single spark application and use some internal time scheduler to run these jobs in parallel. So what is advisable??

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are looking for SparkJobServer (https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver). Using the SparkJobServer, you can submit spark job dynamically through REST interface and get the result.